# How would you measure the pressure on a plate in flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, gas

I want to figure out how much pressure is being imparted on a plate perpendicular to flow in a pipe. Similar to this setup,

[image]

Some initial thinking is that I could just measure the static pressure before and after this area and that pressure difference would be a pretty good analog for the psi being experienced by the plate.

For example if a transducer reads 10psi before and 5psi after, then the plate is experiencing 10-5=5psi. If the area of the plate face is 10in^2 then is under 10*5=50lbs of force.

Is this correct thinking?

Comment: Update I talked with ChatbotGPT about the topic and it referenced several papers verbatim that say the pressure acting on the plate is actually the AVERAGE of the pressure upstream and downstream, (P1+P2)/2. But I don't understand why it isn't the difference.

Comment: Is pressure directional or isotropic?